# Showing dialog fragment throws "can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" exception

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

Sometimes and on some devices dialog fragment crashes the activity because of the above mentioned illegalstateexception

I have tried shownow() which helped only on some devices, but the problem still exists.

```
val dialog = CustomDialogFragment.newInstance(false, correctAnswer, true)
dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "alert")
```

I need the dialog instance for future use, otherwise I would use show instantly after newInstance() . What is the possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I discovered the problem was caused by Android issue, I had the following workaround solution: just override show() method of the dialog fragment as it is below:

```
 @Override
 public void show(@NonNull FragmentManager manager, @Nullable String tag) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(this, tag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
 }
```

Comment: But this is only a Hack, and it could break the UI sometimes.
You can check it here, its well written.
https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this issue is you try to show FragmentDialog activity has changed its state to onPause().

To handle this you must check life cycle state before showing your dialog

```
if(lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)){
   val dialog = CustomDialogFragment.newInstance(false, correctAnswer, true)
   dialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "alert")
}
```

Comment: Yes when Activity will be stopped it will not show dialog, make sense

Comment: sometimes i got the problem when activity is still running.